# Removing a region in the image

Tags: image, matlab

I want to eliminate a specific region in my image using MATLAB. For this, i converted my image into binary. now both the wanted and unwanted (region to be removed) exhibits same spatial characteristics (when i used regionprops() function). The only difference is the position of the regions in the image. Is there any command to do this job...

Eliminating the region means setting the pixel intensity to 0 in the specific region

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? Set the intensity to 0?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mask that is (e.g.) TRUE where you want to remove the region, you can do:

```
myImage[myMask] = 0;
```

If it's TRUE where you want to *keep* the region, you can do:

```
myImage[~myMask] = 0;
```

Is that what you mean? (Update your question with a small amount of code reproducing your problem and we'll be able to tailor our answers better).